# Looking for existing Electromyograph EMG/EEG, or voltage messages

Tags: ros, ros2, messages, ros-groovy, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in the process of implementing a ROSBag writer for an electromyograh device.

Before implementing my own messages, I would like to know if such messages already exist.

Basically I al looking for Electromyograph EMG/EEG messages, or, if they don't exist, a basic voltage message of the type:

```
Header header
float64 voltage
float64 variance
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306234/looking-for-existing-electromyograph-emg/eeg,-or-voltage-messages/) by [Vicente Penades](https://answers.ros.org/users/38071/vicente-penades/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2018-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-10-19**:
I don't know if there already exists the message you need. But you can create your own ROS message and use that. Look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) for more information.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-19**:
.. that could become a standard in the (near) future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a message set for EEG/EMG.

There was a lightning talk about a (consumer) EEG device last ROSCon ([this one](https://roscon.ros.org/2018/presentations/ROSCon2018_Lightning1_2.pdf)), but that doesn't seem to include reusable messages.

Might make sense to propose some new msgs ..

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0